Need to replace mesh with new one but keep same weight info
I have 2 meshes here, the one on the left I originally rigged, then the new one on the right  which I need to copy over the exact armature and weight information too, what is the best way to do so? 

Look up the Data Transfer modifier.

Set the two objects in the same spot, overlapping each other, add to the second object a Data Transfer modifier, targeting the weighted object, tick the Vertex Data and Vertex Group options, click on "Generate Data Layers" button, then apply the modifier (Ctrl A).
You can try different mapping options, but generally the default "Nearest Vertex" works well.
Then, if you want the rig to control the new object, parent them with Ctr P, choosing "Armature deform" as parenting option.


This worked perfect, thanks so much!
